# build a web page at runtime with python?

Tags: python

I am trying to build static pages, to display data on my internal website.

I would like to grab data from various text files, so every time that new data is created; I simply need to run again the script and the page is created with the new data.

I can't use JS or other runtime languages since my server allows only static pages; so I opted for python, to build the static pages.

Now the question is: how do I write such script, that allow me to build a web page?
All the data that I need is 3-4 lines, so the page is not so complex. I tried to create an empty page, and then try to modify the content via python but it was a disaster; then I thought that it would be probably simpler to build the whole page from scratch every time.

To be clear, I am making a simple page with white background, and some text on it, adjusted so it is nice to read; no graphic, no animations, nothing; just pure old school HTML.

Is there a template to do what I am trying to achieve? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like this?

I'm using the [yattag](http://www.yattag.org) library to define the template.

```
from yattag import Doc

def homepage_content():
    return {
        'text': open('/home/username/texts/homepage_text.txt').read(),
        'title': open('/home/username/texts/homepage_title.txt').read()
    }

def page_template(content):
    doc, tag, text = Doc().tagtext()
    with tag('html'):
        with tag('head'):
            with tag('title'):
                text(content['title'])
        with tag('body'):
            with tag('div', id = 'main'):
                text(content['text'])
    return doc.getvalue()

def create_homepage():
    with open('/home/username/www/index.html', "w") as fp:
        fp.write(page_template(homepage_content()))
```

Comment: I believe yes...what does the page look like? Checking this library that you mentioned, so I can confirm. Thanks!